# How to fit table which is having a tick mark inside beamer slide

Tags: tables

I am preparing my presentation using a beamer. I want to insert a table with a tick mark inside, I used `$\checkmark$`. How to do achieve this

```
\documentclass{beamer}






\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Time-line}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|c|l|c|l|c|}
\hline
                                                                          & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Status}                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{2-8} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Assigned\\ Task\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Work partially completed}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Work fully completed} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Work yet to start} & Documentation \\ \hline
Task 1                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} $\Checkmark$}}             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                  &               \\ \hline
Task 2                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                  & $\Checkmark$  \\ \hline
Task 3                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                  & $\Checkmark$  \\ \hline
Task 4                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\Checkmark$}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                  &               \\ \hline
Task 5                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\Checkmark$}      &               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is `\Checkmark` defined? Probably you want to use `\checkmark` instead of `$\Checkmark$`?

Comment: What's the purpose of all the `\multicolumn` commands? Wouldn't a table with 5 columns be sufficient?

Comment: I generated table  using online table generator, they used this package

Comment: Better switch to a different table generator or start manually generating table code. While it does indeed work, there is a lot of unnecessary code involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced `$\Checkmark$` with `\checkmark` and removed the superfluous `\multicolumn` commands as well as the unnecessary columns. To make the table narrower, I have introduced linebreaks in the column headers. In the following MWE I have also included some alternative layouts for the table.

In order to change the color of the checkmark, use `\textcolor{red}{\checkmark}` or any other color of your choice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{calc} % used in third example
\usepackage{booktabs} % Used in fourth example

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Time-line}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\thead{Status}}                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{2-5} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{Assigned\\ Task}} 
    &  \thead{Work\\ partially\\ completed} 
        & \thead{Work\\ fully\\ completed} 
            & \thead{Work\\ yet to\\ start} 
                & \thead{Documentation}    \\ \hline
Task 1  & \checkmark &            &            &            \\ \hline
Task 2  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ \hline
Task 3  &            &            &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
Task 4  &            & \checkmark &            &            \\ \hline
Task 5  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Time-line}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\thead{Status}}                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{2-5} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{Assigned\\ Task}} 
    &  \thead{Work\\ partially\\ completed} 
        & \thead{Work\\ fully\\ completed} 
            & \thead{Work\\ yet to\\ start} 
                & \thead{Documentation}    \\ \hline
Task 1  & \checkmark &            &            &            \\ \hline
Task 2  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ \hline
Task 3  &            &            &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
Task 4  &            & \checkmark &            &            \\ \hline
Task 5  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Time-line}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{completed}}|}c|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Assigned\\ Task}}  
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\thead{Status}}                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{2-5} 
    &  \thead{Work\\ partially\\ completed} 
        & \thead{Work\\ fully\\ completed} 
            & \thead{Work\\ yet to\\ start} 
                & \thead{Documentation}    \\ \hline
Task 1  & \checkmark &            &            &            \\ \hline
Task 2  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ \hline
Task 3  &            &            &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
Task 4  &            & \checkmark &            &            \\ \hline
Task 5  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{Time-line}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule  
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Status}}                                                                                                                                               \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
\thead{Assigned\\ Task}
    &  \thead{Work\\ partially\\ completed} 
        & \thead{Work\\ fully\\ completed} 
            & \thead{Work\\ yet to\\ start} 
                & \thead{Documentation}    \\ \midrule
Task 1  & \checkmark &            &            &            \\ 
Task 2  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ 
Task 3  &            &            &            & \checkmark \\ 
Task 4  &            & \checkmark &            &            \\ 
Task 5  &            &            & \checkmark &            \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: small doubt, How to change the tick mark color to red?

Comment: To change the color of the checkmark, use `\textcolor` as usually.

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `tabularx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\Checkmark{\textcolor{blue}{\checkmark}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Time-line}
    \begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X| *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\multirow{3.2}{=}{\centering    Assigned Task}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Status of Work}           \\ \cline{2-5}
        &   partially completed 
            &   fully completed 
                &   yet to start 
                    &   Documen\-tation     \\ \hline
Task 1  &   $\Checkmark$
            &   &   &                               \\ \hline
Task 2  &   &   &   & $\Checkmark$                  \\ \hline
Task 3  &   &   &   & $\Checkmark$                  \\ \hline
Task 4  &   &   $\Checkmark$
                &   &                               \\ \hline
Task 5  &   &   &   $\Checkmark$    &               \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```